# Why can't upload aab file to Google Play Console?

Tags: android

I try Add capabilities to shortcuts file:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/adding-capabilities

This is my shortcuts file:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="compose"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.googleassistantdemo"
            android:targetClass="com.googleassistantdemo.MainActivity" />
        <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
             here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
             they launch this shortcut. -->
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.CREATE_MESSAGE" />
    </shortcut>
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.START_EXERCISE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.googleassistantdemo"
            android:targetClass="com.googleassistantdemo.MainActivity">
            <parameter
                android:name="exercise.name"
                android:key="exerciseType"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

I had build ok, but I can't upload to Google Play Console to test
It occur error:

```
An APK or App Bundle file that you upload encounters an error regarding the XML configuration for the shortcuts file as follows: The element "<shortcut>" is missing the required attribute "android:shortcutId"
```

Why can't upload aab file to Google Play Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: changed from minSdkVersion = 21 to minSdkVersion = 22